# How to render tooltip on hover - but downwards direction

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, mousehover

Sorry for not providing any working code, but right now my tooltip is rendered "above" the mouse pointer when on hover. But I want it to render 'below' the mouse pointer.

Can you suggest what I should look into?

This is confidential code so cannot share snippets.

This is one of the attributes `box-sizing : border-box` if that helps.

Thanks.

Edit: Added some code:

````
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { 
    0% { opacity: 0;} 
    100% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn { 
    0% { opacity: 0;} 
    100% { opacity: 1;}
}

#hbox_tooltip {

    @include box-sizing(border-box);
    width: 480px;
    max-height: 206px;
    padding: 0 20px 16px 20px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10), 0 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: $b-z-implicit-hover;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;

    &.fadeIn {
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.2s linear;
        -moz-animation: fadeIn 0.2s linear;
        -o-animation: fadeIn 0.2s linear;
        animation: fadeIn 0.2s linear;
    }

    .entity_title {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .entity_image {
        margin: 16px 0 0 16px;
        float: right;
    }

    .entity_description {
        margin: 16px 0 0 0;
        line-height: 17px;
    }

    .entity_source {
        margin: 12px 0 20px 0;
        float: left;
        display: block;
    }

    &:hover, &:focus {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    &:before {
        @include box-sizing(border-box);
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 99%;
        left: 33%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin-left: -10px;
        border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
        box-shadow: -4px 4px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.18);
        border-color: transparent transparent white white;
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    &.tooltip_b:before {
        top: 1%;
        transform: rotate(-225deg);
        box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.18);
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Is it your code that displays the tooltip?  Or built-in `title='tooltip'`?  If it's your code, then you'll have some calculation that determines the position - change that calculation.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes it is my code. I can take a deeper look.
The data is in a nested div with name "tip_data".

Comment: How it's triggered is irrelevant - it's how it's shown that you should include the code for.  Positioning a div based on mouse cursor position should not include "confidential" data - see [mcve] - only include the *minimum* code (not all your code).

Comment: @freedomn-m I've added some code - does it help? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Not really, need to see it in action.  The border/shadow are irrelevant.   Where's the code to calculate/set based on the mouse position?  (per question "*below mouse pointer*") or is it positioned based on the element?  with :hover to show it?

Comment: @freedomn-m yes it uses :hover to show it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251842/discussion-between-karan-saxena-and-freedomn-m).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the tooltip below the cursor (in downwards direction), I would recommend you to use the built-in **title='tooltip**' of html, will make your job easier.

Otherwise, if you need to do it using css, you need to just **position it**, for example:

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 100px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px; //Half the Width
}
```

Comment: There's so many reasons not to use built-in tooltip.  Here's a couple: no styling, inaccurate positioning, no HTML, auto-wrap, can't be seen on some collaboration apps/screen sharing (eg teams).   Reason to use it:  easy, auto-positions itself on the screen.

Comment: I added some new code above - can you see and suggest a better way? Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom tooltip with below code:

```
&:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: I added some new code above - can you see and suggest a better way? Thanks a lot for helping.